# h1 text appears above a side-sliding navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index, mobile-website

I am trying to make a mobile friendly site, which includes a menu that slides out from the side when a button is tapped. I am using Bootstrap for a slideshow, which includes h1 text on the images. Like in this picture (don't have enough reputation points to put one in directly, sorry) https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuaQ4.png. Please note that this was not taken on a mobile browser/device, but from Google Chrome.

The problem is that the text on the slideshows and the click dots overlap the menu, which I don't want to happen. I want the menu to be clear and clean, without that.

I tried to use z-index values to correct this, but it won't work no matter what I assign to each one. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please explain the problem a little more. You tried to use z-index to correct what? The menu goes over the slideshow?

Comment: What is the actual problem??

Comment: I added a better explanation of what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news! I found the problem. I was trying to apply the z-index only to the h1 elements, because that was what was overlapping the menu. I tried instead giving the entire Bootstrap Carousel a z-index of 1, by adding:

```
#myCarousel {
z-index: 1;
}
```

To my CSS page. And also assigning all the elements that make up the sliding menu a z-index value of 9.

Answer (score 0):

When using z-index you must make sure that the element you are trying to apply z-index to, must have position other than static, such as position: relative; or position: absolute;

Comment: If "position: fixed;" would also work, I think that is what is applied.